# Minimize overlap in no gap scheduling

Tags: algorithm, graph

Suppose we should always had at least one doctor on duty in hospital. There are n doctors(d1,d2,....,dn), the k-th doctor is availabe from time a_k to time b_k. To simplify the problem, suppose that the k-th doctor always work from time a_k to time b_k but we can choose which doctors come to work or not come to work. The goal is to minimize the the total overlap of working time. This is not a Interval scheduling problem because there cannot be gap between the interval(suppose this is achievable) but the interval overlap must be minimized.

I am trying to approach this problem change it to a graph and use shortest path algorithm: Let the source vertex be the first doctor come to work and the terminal be the doctor leave hospital latest be the terminal. Let the the edge weighted with the time overlaping between doctors.

I am wondering: does this kind of problem have generic name which I can use to find some reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Search term

It may help to search for "minimum cost interval cover" based on the idea that if we assign each doctor a cost equal to the time spent, then minimizing the total cost is equivalent to minimizing the overlap because the amount of overlap will equal "total doctor time" minus "total time to be covered".

However, searching for this doesn't actually seem too helpful.

### Algorithm

You could solve this using dynamic programming.  The idea is to solve a sub-problem f(t) which gives the lowest amount of interval if we want to cover all times from the start time (let us call this time 0) up to exactly time t.

Clearly f(0) is 0 because no doctors are required.

Assume now we have worked out the value of f(t) for all times t less than or equal to n.  We can work out f(n+1) by a simple algorithm:

1. Consider all doctors who finish at time n+1.
2. For each of these, consider all times t between the start time `a_k`, and the end_time `b_k`.  `t` will represent the time that has already been covered by other doctors, so the amount of overlap is equal to `t - a_k`.  The cost (i.e. total amount of overlap) using this doctor is therefore equal to `f(t) + (t-a_k)`
3. Set f(n+1) equal to the smallest value of f(t)+(t-a_k) found (or infinity if no doctors finish at this time)

Starting with n=0, this procedure then allows us to compute f(1), f(2), ..., until all values have been found.